# Lazy slice in python3

Tags: python, list

I have a huge list (~1_800_000 items) in python which is constructed using `map()` function from about 1000 JSON files. I want to check few first items to be sure that script is working correctly. I'm doing it like this:

```py
items = map(lambda file: load_json(file), file_list)
print(list(items)[:5])
```

Converting map to list takes about 5-10 seconds, is it possible to take few first items without converting `map` result to `list`?

Comment: [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)?

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to create a lambda if you are going to pass its argument to another function. you can directly pass the function to `map`: `items = map(load_json, file_list)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
items = map(lambda file: load_json(file), file_list)
print([next(items) for _ in range(5)])
```

Or use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), which has the slight advantage that it will not fail if you have less than five items:

```
items = map(lambda file: load_json(file), file_list)
print(list(itertools.islice(items, 5)))
```

Note that both of these consume the first elements in `items`, so if you want to "peek" these elements and then get the whole list, you will need to preppend these items first.